# sqlte3 error no such column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to run this command from the shell:

```
sqlite3 salesShare1.db  "
 select 
  UsersSale.saleSpecificProduct,
  UsersSale.fAtMall,
  Users.name,
  Users.gender,
  Stores.storeName 
 FROM 
   UsersSale 
    INNER JOIN (Users INNER JOIN Stores ON Users.userID = UsersSale.userID) ON 
      Stores.storeID = UsersSale.saleStoreID 
 ORDER BY UsersSale.saleID";
```

> Error: no such column: Users.name

I created all the tables and columns.

```
sqlite3 salesShare1.db  "select * FROM Users ";
1|hezi|0|||
```

'hezi' is Users.name

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where is your create statement (alternatively execute this command `select * from sqlite_master`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try please

```
select us.saleSpecificProduct,
   us.fAtMall,u.name,
   u.gender,st.storeName 
   from UsersSale us,Users u,Stores st 
   where u.userID=us.userID and st.storeID=us.saleStoreID 
   order by us.saleID
```

or

```
 select us.saleSpecificProduct,
   us.fAtMall,u.name,
   u.gender,st.storeName 
   from UsersSale us 
   inner join Users u
    on u.userID=us.userID
   inner join Stores st 
   on st.storeID=us.saleStoreID 
   order by us.saleID
```

---

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your inner join is a little ackward.

Shot in the dark, but my guess is you need to join in the Users table:

```
 select 
  us.saleSpecificProduct,
  us.fAtMall,
  u.name,
  u.gender,
  s.storeName 
 FROM 
   UsersSale us
    INNER JOIN Users u ON u.userID = us.userID
    INNER JOIN Stores s ON s.storeID = us.saleStoreID 

 ORDER BY us.saleID
```

Answer (score 0):

Display the schema for your table in the sqlite3 tool and confirm your column name is what you thought it was. Maybe you mis-typed the name.